# Finding n-Most Popular Using Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How should I structure a Linq query to return a List or Ienumerable of the most popular Tags in my db (I am using EF4.1 by the way).

Currently I have:

```
  var tagsListing = db.Tags
                            .GroupBy(q => q.Name)
                                .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                                .Take(5)
                                .Select();
```

I think I am part of the way there, but I am unsure of how to structure the Select statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the name and the count, just:

```
.Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

EDIT: If you want the complete tags as well, you *could* use:

```
.Select(g => new { Tags = g, Count = g.Count() })
```

which would give you a sequence of *groups* of tags, all with the same name within a group. Or you might only want the *first* tag within each group, e.g.

```
.Select(g => g.First())
```

It's not clear what a Tag consists of, or what *exactly* you want in the results.

Comment: How about if I didnt want to return anonymous types but the actual Tags.

Comment: That looks like it is just selecting the string and not the entire Tag object. It is returning an IQueryable<string>, ideally I want to return Ienumerable<Tag>.

Comment: @Judo: Have edited... bear in mind you're grouping *multiple* tags with the same name - are you happy to just get the first (possibly arbitrary) one of each name?

Comment: Thanks, .Select(g => g.First())  worked fine as it returned the name for each of the top x number of most used Tags. The Tags are actually part of a many-to-many relationship with Articles, so the Name property will be repeated and so returning the First() won't be arbitary. Sorry the question wasn't clearer. I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Select` call could look like this:

```
.Select(gp => gp.Key)
```

That will give you an `IEnumerable<string>` of your most popular tags (assuming that `Name` is a `string`).

Answer (score 1):

You've written a perfectly workable query and do not need to call `.Select`

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Tag>> tagsListing = db.Tags
  .GroupBy(q => q.Name)
  .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
  .Take(5);

List<IGrouping<string, Tag>> results = tagListing.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to select the names like this:

```
.Select(gp => gp.Key);
```